# Symfony 4 file upload with entity

Tags: forms, symfony, file-upload, symfony4

I'm working on my module and one part is where you can add new backgrounds to the database to use in a slideshow.

I have a `SlideshowBackground` entity with 3 properties:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=150)
 */
private $image;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
 */
private $imageAlt;
```

And basically, the image is the string of the uploaded file, including the relative path.

I have the following `SlideshowBackgroundType` as form for the adding slideshow background page:

```
class SlideshowBackgroundType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('image', FileType::class, [
            'required' => true
        ]);
        $builder->add('imageAlt', TextType::class, ['required' => true]);
    }
}
```

However, if I submit my form and check `$form->getData()`, it contains the following data:

```
SlideshowBackground {#419 ▼
-id: null
-image: "C:\wamp64\tmp\php5B96.tmp"
-imageAlt: "ty"
}
```

However, this way I can't get the original uploaded file name. I use the following code in my controller:

```
$slideshowBackground = new SlideshowBackground();
$form = $this->createForm(SlideshowBackgroundType::class, $slideshowBackground);
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

How can I use `SlideshowBackground` entity but also be able to have a file uploaded that's not directly mapped to the `image`?

I tried to modify my `image` field to the following:

```
$builder->add('image', FileType::class, [
    'required' => false,
    'mapped' => false
]);
```

But then I get the same result from `$form->getData()`, however with the `image` column as null.

Also, when I try to submit with the last code, I get the following error on `image`:

```
This value should not be null.
```

I know the `image` property in `SlideshowBackground` is required, and it should be, but it doesn't work as `image` isn't defined when submitting with the `mapped => false`. Any way to go around this problem?

Comment: Look at the controller code in the [docs example](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html).  Be sure to filter the results of getClientOriginalName() since it could be an attack vector.

Comment: @Cerad I did look there but again I couldn't figure it out as it gives an additional problem. My form uses my entity which has a property `image` which is required, and since when submitting it is null, it throws errors. However, `image` should be required AFAIK as backgrounds need to have an image specified.

Comment: Nevermind, I detected my stupidity, I got the right data and I found the problem. Thanks anyways

Comment: Did it have to do with not setting mapped to false?  Just curious.

Comment: Actually it doesn't work. I changed my `image` input in the form builder to `imageupload`, it does add a new unmapped input type. However, my form doesn't work as `image` in `SlideshowBackground` entity is null which cannot happen. Thus, `$form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()` will return false. I only detected me looking at `$form->getData` and that only returns the entity (and not extra fields). So I'm able to get the uploaded image from the form but I cannot submit my form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the OP is still having a problem but not sure.  In any event, this works:

```
class SlideshowBackgroundType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('image', FileType::class, [
            'required' => true,
            'mapped' => false, // *** NEED THIS ***
        ]);
        $builder->add('imageAlt', TextType::class, ['required' => true]);
        $builder->add('upload', SubmitType::class);
    }
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => SlideshowBackground::class,
        ]);
    }
...
class IndexController extends AbstractController
{
    /** @Route("/upload", name="upload") */
    public function upload(Request $request)
    {
        $slideshowBackground = new SlideshowBackground();
        $form = $this->createForm(SlideshowBackgroundType::class, $slideshowBackground);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            /** @var UploadedFile $imageFile */
            $imageFile = $form['image']->getData();
            dump($imageFile);

            // It is up to you to get the original filename per the example in the docs
            $originalFilename = pathinfo($imageFile->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            // this is needed to safely include the file name as part of the URL
            //$safeFilename = transliterator_transliterate('Any-Latin; Latin-ASCII; [^A-Za-z0-9_] remove; Lower()', $originalFilename);
            //$newFilename = $safeFilename.'-'.uniqid().'.'.$brochureFile->guessExtension();

            $slideshowBackground->setImage($originalFilename); // *** NEED THIS ***
            dump($slideshowBackground);
            ...
        }
```

---

Edit by OP:

This answer is correct, however, for future reference / for other people, keep note that if the following code is uncommented in `config/packages/validator.yaml`, this will **not** work:

```
auto_mapping:
            App\Entity\: []
```

So if this code doesn't work check if the auto_mapping code is commented out.

Edit by the answerer:

I allowed the above edit because apparently it fixed the problem.  However, I have been unable to reproduce the issue.  Pretty sure there is more code being executed between $form->handleRequest and $form->isValid.

Comment: This gives the error `This value should not be null.` on the `image` upload field. And this means `$form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()` is also false. This is most likely because `image` is a property in `SlideshowBackground` entity that is required but not set.

Comment: @JoshuaBakker You have something else going on.  I tested the code before posting and it works as expected.  The mapped attribute is smart enough to allow the property to pass the "is not null" test.  Here is a github repo of my working code: https://github.com/cerad/upload

Comment: I see your SlideshowBackground isn't a database entity class. Maybe that's the problem. I just realize I never said it was a database entity class.

Comment: It basically is.  I just never added the annotations.  The forms component does not care about doctrine annotations.  If you have some additional validation going on somewhere (perhaps a form listener or something) then that could be causing the problem.

Comment: Not really, I have created the form using my form type class (extending from AbstractType) and I've used the entity class constructor in the createform as data. And I do get the error and I don't use anything else that could break it AFAIK.

Comment: Maybe update your question to show what "used the entity class constructor in the createform as data." means.  Your current code shows a simple new operator.  Same as mine.  Maybe make a github repo of your code and I'll take a look.  And if you have not already, consider fetching out my repo and confirming for yourself that it works as expected.

Comment: I added configureOptions to my answer's form type to explicitly set the data_class.  Should not make any difference in this case but it is recommended.  It's possible it might help your app.

Comment: Unfortunately due to it being a project of my work I cannot simply make a public git repository (and in case you're wondering, there wasn't anybody who could help me with this available at the time, hence the reason I made this question). The configureOptions didn't fix it. I'll clone your repo and see if it works how it should and if so I'll see what the ** is happening in our project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198372/discussion-between-joshua-bakker-and-cerad).